# Do mongo aggregations allow in-query string manipulation?

Tags: regex, mongodb

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654711/mongo-aggregation-apply-regex-grouping-string-processing-on-project)

What I'm specifically looking for are analogs for the LEFT, SUBSTRING and REPLACE functions from SQL in mongo.

After researching this for some time, I can't find any direct analogs for those functions nor am I seasoned enough with mongodb that I can see another way of performing an equivalent operation.

An example of a similar query that I'm looking for is as follows:

```
REPLACE(case when LEFT(title,1) = '"' then SUBSTRING(title, 2, LEN(title)) else title end,char(9),'')
```

Which is to be used as part of a $project.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String operations you need:

```
{ $concat: [ <expression1>, <expression2>, ... ] }
{ $substr: [ <string>, <start>, <length> ] }
```

Examples:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", quarter: "13Q1", "description" : "product 1" }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", quarter: "13Q4", "description" : "product 2" }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "XYZ1", quarter: "14Q2", "description" : null }
```

Concat:

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
      { $project: { itemDescription: { $concat: [ "$item", " - ", "$description" ] } } }
   ]
)
```

Substr:

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
          {
        item: 1,
            yearSubstring: { $substr: [ "$quarter", 0, 2 ] },
            quarterSubtring: { $substr: [ "$quarter", 2, -1 ] }
          }
      }
   ]
)
```

Look at the string operations [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#string-expressions). I think you should combine [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)-operator with the string ones.

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply! I'll have a look now.

Comment: Substring solves the SUBSTRING and LEFT problems, but I can't see any way of replicating the REPLACE behaviour using the given commands. Am I missing something/is there more that can help replicate that behaviour? I seems the key missing element is a string lookup operation.